# Getting the row count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following sql query. I want to get all row count. Anybody can help me?

```
WITH numberedrows 
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10 f_feeid_pk, 
                                f_code, 
                                f_description, 
                                f_fee, 
                                f_areaid_ind_fk, 
                                a_name_ind, 
                                p_name_ind, 
                                s_name_ind, 
                                b_name_ind, 
                                Row_number() 
                                  OVER ( 
                                    ORDER BY b_name_ind, s_name_ind, p_name_ind, 
                                  a_name_ind, f_code ASC) AS 
                                RowNumber 
         FROM   t_fee 
                INNER JOIN t_area 
                        ON f_areaid_ind_fk = a_areaid_pk 
                INNER JOIN t_project 
                        ON a_projectid_fk = p_projectid_pk 
                INNER JOIN t_section 
                        ON p_sectionid_fk = s_sectionid_pk 
                INNER JOIN t_branch 
                        ON s_branchid_fk = b_branchid_pk 
         WHERE  f_feeid_pk > 0) 
SELECT * 
FROM   numberedrows
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace that `DISTINCT TOP 10` with `DISTINCT` to get all the distinct results, assuming you are interested only in count of distinct, otherwise remove the DISTINCT as well, and then change your `SELECT` over CTE to use `COUNT(*)`

```
WITH numberedrows 
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT f_feeid_pk, 
                                f_code, 
                                f_description, 
                                f_fee, 
                                f_areaid_ind_fk, 
                                a_name_ind, 
                                p_name_ind, 
                                s_name_ind, 
                                b_name_ind, 
                                Row_number() 
                                  OVER ( 
                                    ORDER BY b_name_ind, s_name_ind, p_name_ind, 
                                  a_name_ind, f_code ASC) AS 
                                RowNumber 
         FROM   t_fee 
                INNER JOIN t_area 
                        ON f_areaid_ind_fk = a_areaid_pk 
                INNER JOIN t_project 
                        ON a_projectid_fk = p_projectid_pk 
                INNER JOIN t_section 
                        ON p_sectionid_fk = s_sectionid_pk 
                INNER JOIN t_branch 
                        ON s_branchid_fk = b_branchid_pk 
         WHERE  f_feeid_pk > 0) 
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM numberedrows;
```

Comment: Thanks Vikdor. That's I need exactly. Great job.

Comment: DISTINCT doesn't affect the result in this particular case. DISTINCT is evaluated after SELECT, and SELECT would produce rows without duplicates, "thanks" to `ROW_NUMBER().